# How to display all orders (or) posts by a user Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to create a website called froto in this people hire vehicles for goods transportation I am successful in collecting data from users and display data to admin with middleware.but now I want to display data to user i.e. to generate order summary to user immediately after they hired a vehicle which I am not able to do
     This is my controller store method and show method

```
 public function store(PostsCreateRequest $request)
{
    //

    if ($user = Auth::user()) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->posts()->create($input);
        return redirect('admin.post.show');
    }
    return redirect('/login');

}


public function show($id)
{
    //
    $users = User::all();
    $posts = Post::all();
     $posts = $post->where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->get();


    return view('admin.post.show', compact('posts'));
}
```

My routes

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){

Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
Route::resource('admin/post', 'AdminPostsController', ['only' => [
    'index',
]]);});Route::resource('admin/post', 'AdminPostController', ['only' => [
'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy', 'show']]);
```

My show.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>order summary</h1>
    @foreach ($posts as $post) <h1> {{$post->user->name}}</h1>... @endforeach
@stop
```

please help me to generate an order summary when user click on hire a vehicle button thankshire a vehicle page:
[image: hire a vehicle page]

Here are screenshots of my projecthome page:
[image: home page]

Answer (score 1):

```
App/User-- model
public function posts(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id', 'id');
}

App/Post -- model

public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function show($id){
 $user = User::findOrFail($id);
 $posts = $user->posts;
 return view('admin.post.show', compact('posts'));
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: good thanks, but instead of 'App\User' it seems standard to use User::class instead